# Чи є синонімами слова "дерев'яни́ти" та "дерев'яні́ти"?

Tags: синоніми

СУМ-20

> **[ДЕРЕВ'ЯНИ́ТИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21639&page=736)** и́ть, недок., кого, що. Робити нечутливим, як дерево. *Мертвіла приморожена щока, терпли, крижаніючи, руки. Безсоння
> шаленої ночі дерев'янило мозок* (Іван Ле).
>
> **[ДЕРЕВ'ЯНІ́ТИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21640&page=736)** і́ю, і́єш, недок. **1.** Ставати твердим, як дерево. У дорослих клітинах у багатьох рослин змінюється хімічний
> склад оболонки, а саме: вона може дерев'яніти, ослизнюватися,
> просочуватись кремнеземом та ін. (з навч. літ.).
> **2.** перен. Втрачати чутливість; терпнути, німіти. *У Марка підгиналися ноги. Дерев'яніли руки. Цілу ніч простояв він біля
> штурвала, не маючи жодної хвилини відпочинку* (М. Трублаїні).

Чи можна використовувати слово *дерев'янити* синонімом до *дерев'яніти* (знач.2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

З означень, які ви навели, випливає, що:

1. Дерев'янити можна когось чи щось, тобто, якийсь об'єкт.

> Безсоння дерев'янило *(кого? що?)* мозок.

2. Дерев'яніти може сам суб'єкт.

> Дерев'яніли *(хто? що?)* руки.

Отже, лоґічно, що не можна використовувати ці слова як синоніми.